# logrotate - compression files modified x number of days

Tags: linux, logrotate

Is there a way to get logrotate to only compress files modified X number of days ago (e.g. mtime +2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can use delaycompress to wait one more cycle. Basically if you rotate daily then it will keep yesterdays logs uncompressed.

Besides that you could try not using logrotate to compress the files and write a bash script to run like once a day and compress all files older than a certain date.

Here is a tutorial to bash that I personally like: http://www.linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial

Answer (score 14):

One option could be to use `logrotate` to rotate to a different extension, then use `logrotate` to rotate into compressed files:

```
/var/log/raw.log {
  daily
  nocompress
  extension .old
  }

/var/log/*.old {
  daily
  compress
  delaycompress
  rotate 10
  }
```

This Rube Goldberg contraption will result in the following:

```
raw.log
raw.log.old
raw.log.old.1
raw.log.old.2.gz
raw.log.old.3.gz
```

Thus you have two archived days of logs which are uncompressed.

Answer (score -1):

Could you do something like the following?

```
/var/log/access.log {
    daily
    nocompress
}

/var/log/access.7.log {
     daily
     compress
}
```

I think that will give you something like

```
access.log
access.1.log
access.2.log
access.3.log    
access.4.log
access.5.log
access.6.log
access.7.log.gz
access.8.log.gz
access.log
```

Comment: Any verdict?  this looks awesome

Comment: This is not working because the uncompress logs are not removed. A compressed version is just added.